# Respostas retiradas

Tags: debate

Fiz a pergunta [Assinar NFs-e em C# gera erro Elemento Reference mal formado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117568/assinar-nfs-e-em-c-gera-erro-elemento-reference-mal-formado), e ela foi **protegida**. E teve 2 respostas de pessoas que resolveu o problema.

A dúvida é:
Eu posso responder a pergunta, neste caso, já que as respostas que me ajudaram foram excluídas.

Comment: Essa aqui resolveu o problema? `Removi a atualização KB3140768,reiniciei a maquina e funcionou.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3141780
Agora vou tentar procurar uma solução para o meu código.` ou `A atualização KB3135996 também faz surgir o mesmo problema, ao removê-la tudo volta a funcionar. Também estou buscando uma solução para o problema.`

Comment: Depende da atualização que a máquina tem. Eu tirei a outra atualização e funcionou. Mas somente tenho no pc de casa e atualização que tirei.

Comment: Se você tem uma solução e pode dar uma boa resposta, responda, e aceite ela.

Comment: mas tem problema de ser somente a questão de tirar a atualização do windows voltar a funcionar?

Comment: Marlon, não tem problema. Talvez até algumas das respostas tenham sido indevidamente excluídas. Vou olhar isso com calma depois, e se for o caso desfaço a remoção

Comment: @rray agora que vi que você postou as duas respostas. Ao meu ver ambas funcionam. Mas eu somente tirei a KB3135996, e funcionou. Queres que eu responda a minha pergunta ou você volta a resposta que foi excluída?

Comment: @marlon.tiedt a KB3140768 parece então não mudar em nada no comportamento do seu sistema? Acho que o ideal seria restaurarmos a resposta que melhor responde a sua pergunta, já não tenho tanta certeza  se devemos restaurar todas que tentam responder mas que talvez não acertem em cheio a solução.